# Amplify init or Amplify add env creates auth role name with same previous env

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-cdk, aws-serverless

I had a working environment and I wanted to add a new environment using aws amplify cli. I used the

```
amplify init
```

command and added a new env which is in separate account and it got create successfully. I tried:

```
amplify add env
```

for adding env in the same account but I get the following error:

```
An error occurred when creating the CloudFormation stack
The following resources failed to deploy:
Resource Name: AuthRole (AWS::IAM::Role)
Event Type: create
Reason: ASD-amplify-authrole-{envName} already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:xxx:xxx:stack/amplify-xx-xxx-xx/xxx

Initialization of project failed
Name: AuthRole (AWS::IAM::Role), Event Type: create, Reason: ASD-amplify-authrole-{envName} already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:xxx:xxx:stack/amplify-xx-xxx-xx/xxx, IsCustomResource: false
```

It is copying the auth role name as that of working previous env in both cases.
for the separate account it gets created but in the same it found it already existing.
I have an overriden.ts file generated using `amplify override project` which looks like this.

```js
export function override(resources: AmplifyRootStackTemplate) {
  const authRole = resources.authRole;
  authRole.roleName = `${PRE_FIX}-amplify-authrole-${ENV_NAME}`;
  if (isCrossAccount) {
    const basePolicies = Array.isArray(authRole.policies)
      ? authRole.policies
      : [authRole.policies];
    authRole.policies = [
      ...basePolicies,
      {
        policyName: `${PRE_FIX}-amplify-authrole-assumerole-policy`,
        policyDocument: {
          Version: "2012-10-17",
          Statement: [
            {
              Action: "sts:AssumeRole",
              Resource: `arn:aws:iam::${ACCOUNT_ID}:role/${PRE_FIX}-xxx-${POST_FIX}`,
              Effect: "Allow",
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

I pass these variables `isCrossAccount, ENV_NAME, PRE_FIX, POST_FIX, ACCOUNT_ID` using the `env.ts` file that I created in the same folder and import as "./env".

I tried updating the `env.ts` file and hard coded the name of `ENV_NAME, PRE_FIX, POST_FIX, ACCOUNT_ID` and use them but it always picks the values as from older env.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  _"Use generated resource names, not physical names"_ is a CDK [Best Practice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps).  To avoid naming collisions and other headaches, consider using the default, CDK-generated names for your roles.

Comment: Thanks @fedonev I am using my custom names because I need to append Pre-fix in my role name so they can be assumed by other accounts. Is there a way so I can append the desired Pre-fix and have the original role name concatenated with it ?